# Is the optimizer of a strongly-convex cost function bounded?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let f(x) be strongly-convex. Can its minimizer be unbounded? I suspect not.
Can we obtain a bound on it in relation to the strong-convexity constant?

I believe an equivalent formulation of this question is: Is the minimizer, $x^\star$, of a strongly-convex function, $f(x)$, in a compact or bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is strongly convex, then its minimiser set $\arg\min_x f(x)$ is a singleton. In general, a sufficient condition for the minimiser to be bounded (actually, compact) is that $f$ should be lower semicontinuous and level bounded.